# Swapping the first word with itself 3 times only if there are 4 words only using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Hi I'm trying to solve a problem **only using sed commands** and without using pipeline. But I am allowed to pass the result of a sed command to a file or te read from a file.
EX:

```
sed s/dog/cat/ >| tmp 
or
sed s/dog/cat/ < tmp
```

Anyway lets say I had a file F1 and its contents was :

```
Hello hi 123
if a equals b
you
one abc two three four
dany uri four 123
```

The output should be:

```
if if if a equals b
dany dany dany uri four 123
```

Explanation: the program must only print lines that have exactly 4 words and when it prints them it must print the first word of the line 3 times.

I've tried doing commands like this:

```
sed '/[^ ]*.[^ ]*.[^ ]*/s/[^ ]\+/& & &/' F1
```

or

```
sed 's/[^ ]\+/& & &/' F1
```

but I can't figure out how i can calculate with sed that there are only 4 words in a line.
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed -En 's/^([^[:space:]]+)([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+){3}$/\1 \1 &/p' file
if if if a equals b
dany dany dany uri four 123
```

The above uses a sed that supports EREs with a `-E` option, e.g. GNU and OSX seds).

Comment: I ran your command and got an error: sed: invalid option -- E
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...
looks like it dosent support this option

Comment: `-r` is the equivalent of `-E` in older versions of GNU sed and since `\+` works for you in your question, you must be running a version of GNU sed. Did you by any chance remove the `-n` when you changed `-E` to `-r`?

Comment: @EdMorton yes my bad , thank you for your feedback. -rn works.

Answer (score 1):

If the fields are tab separated

```
sed 'h;s/[^[:blank:]]//g;s/[[:blank:]]\{3\}//;/^$/!d;x;s/\([^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]\)/\1\1\1/' infile
```