# Work only with lines that have 4 words in SED

Tags: regex, unix, sed

How to work with lines that have only 4 words in them with SED?

That’s what I managed to do, but it’s not working:

```
sed -e '/[ ]*[^ ]+[ ]*[^ ]+[ ]*[^ ]+[ ]*[^ ]+[ ]*/!d' -e 'other commands...' fileName
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swapping the first word with itself 3 times only if there are 4 words only using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978693/swapping-the-first-word-with-itself-3-times-only-if-there-are-4-words-only-using)

Answer (score 1):

This should be portable:

```
sed -n '
/^[[:blank:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{3\}[[:alpha:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]*$/ {

    # capture the 1st word of every 4 word line and print it 3 times
    s/^[[:blank:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1 \1 \1/
    p

}
' > temp-file
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I add there another sed command on the same line, or maybe push the result of it to a tmp file?

Comment: You can add as many as you need where I have the comment. I'll add some samples to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but it’s not working as I expected. I want to get a file, show only lines with 4 words, and show the first word in every sentence 3 times. I tried to place s/[^ ]*/& & &/ in the { } but it’s not working.

Comment: Updated the answer. The rest will be left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

`AWK` may be the easier tool for your task. Just check the number of fields in a line is equal to four using the awk built-in variable `NF`.

```
awk 'NF==4' filename
```

would be a good starting point. if you wish to write the changes to file, you can use the inplace edit option of the `GNU AWK` like below

```
gawk -i inplace 'NF==4' filename
```